# simple javascript string calculator

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a simple javascript calculator that will ask user to input name and it will display a number according to input, each letter in string will have a value like a=1 and b=2. If we insert acb in input it should display abc=1+2+3 =6.
thanks

```
<input type="text" id="myText" value="">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="calc"></p>

 <script>
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
   document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Are you `trying`, or are you asking SO to write it for you? Post your code if you want debugging help.

Comment: You might use something like `string.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(i) - 96`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it uses a simple a=1 to z=26 code. If a special character or number is entered, they are treated as 0. This does work for uppercase and lowercase letters.

```js
function myFunction() {
   var x = document.getElementById("myText").value;
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    var temp = x.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(i) - 96;
   if ((temp > 0) & (temp < 27)) {
     total = total + temp;
   }
  }
   document.getElementById("calc").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myText" value="">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="calc"></p>
```

Comment: thank you so much you are a life saver but what if i want to assign different values to char i.e a=4 and b=9

Comment: In that case, you might want to use a switch/case to define a specific value for each letter.